# database result are not showing in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I typed this code but no record is coming from database...I have attached  Ms Access database
Need help please...
the output only says "build successful".

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Db {

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

   //constructor
    public Db(){

        connect();
    }

    //connect funtion
    public void connect(){

        try {
            String driver;
            driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JbdcObdcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String db;
            db="jbdc:obdc:db2";
           //connectin to db 
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(db);


            String sql;
            sql="Select * from Table1";

            rs=st.executeQuery(sql);


            while (rs.next()){

                String fname=rs.getString("FirstName");

                String lname=rs.getString("LastName");

                String age=rs.getString("age");

                System.out.println(fname+" "+lname+" "+age);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
          Db d=new Db();
```

Comment: Any error? Does this table contains data?

Comment: 1) *"build successful"* It seems the IDE is compiling and building the code, as opposed to running it. 2) There seems to be no connection to Swing here. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: .. 4) `public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }` At run-time, that `main` method will achieve exactly nothing.

Comment: i even created a new file for gui frame....
and when i run that it gave me the same result, no solid output.
what should i do please help, need to complete it

Comment: You should create a `main` method that actually does something; currently your program does nothing, because your main method only contains a comment.

Comment: You almost got it right; you need to move the last brace in the snippet (`}`) _after_ `Db d=new Db();` so that the code is executed within `main`.

Comment: @mick mnemmonic thanks for your help....but now the output shows the driver name rather than showing the records from database.

Comment: sun.jdbc.odbc.JbdcObdcDriver
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
this is the output now..but i have added some data in the database so i want that data to be displayed.......:(

Comment: //connectin to db 
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            System.out.println("Database connected");
            
          st=con.createStatement(); //connection to get tables
            String sql;
            sql="Select * from Table1";

this section code is not running......the database is not connecting the file i want to attach...the name of the db file is correct....nd even the print line of "database connection" is working..

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35532520/edit) the question with this information. Nothing in the code you shared should print the driver name, but perhaps you're getting an exception when you're running the program. You could also add `e.printStackTrace()` within the `catch` block to get more information.